# Centering my icons in the middle of the div. OK for handheld devices but not for browsers

Tags: html, css

Please look at the **social** widget on the footer of this site:

https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/

This screen grab is from Microsoft Edge:

[image: Icons]

I can't seem to get those icons to be **centered** under the heading. On my handheld devices (like my iPhone) it does show centered:

[image: Icons - iPhone]

This is the HTML for the widget:

```
<div class="textwidget">
    <div class="social animateblock">
        <div class="fa-icons">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/publictalksoftware/" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/xxx" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="">
            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-youtube-play">
            </i></a>
            <a href="https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/feed/" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="">
            <i class="fa fa-rss"></i></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried setting the margins for left and right to auto but it is not working for browsers. Confused.

Comment: remove `float:left;` from this selector `.social .fa-icons`

Comment: @ZohirSalak Thanks. I can't seem to locate this `float:left` using Element Inspector?

Comment: `line: 784` in this file `https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/wp-content/themes/seos-video-premium/seos-video-premium/style.css?ver=5.3`

Comment: I was able to see it with Firefox browser inspector. I added some custom CSS to my site and now they are centred. Thanks Just got to fins a way to get rid of that "square" that shows to the left... but that is another question.

Comment: That square is a pseud-class added by this class `fa-icons` which is related to font-awesome

Comment: @ZohirSalak Yes, I see it with a `::before` class definition but the value `\f86d` is valid for both font awesome 4 .7 and 5 so I don't get that. Besised, why show an icon there when I have my own ...

Comment: You need to add the class `.fa` or `.fas` that specifies the rest of the styling

Comment: @ZohirSalak At the moment it has: `.fa-icons:before {content: "\f86d";}`

Comment: @ZohirSalak I switched off that symbol: `.social .fa-icons:before {display: none;}`

Comment: Just remove it from the element, tampering with it will affect other icons on the page and worse on the whole site

Comment: @ZohirSalak The widget is part of the theme options. So I can't change that (although I am using a child theme - but my knowledge is limited with child themes).

Answer (score 1):

To center your content, add the following styles to your `.textWidget` class:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

**Note:** *I tweaked the padding to only keep the top 10px spacing. Of course, you can change the padding to whatever you need. It's your project.*

I applied these styles using the developer tools in Google's Chrome browser. Your mileage may vary, but the styles seemed to keep pretty stable across the different breakpoints you have set on your site. Here are some screenshots of my test:

Here's the element before applying flexbox (viewport width: 824px)
[image: .textWidget before flexbox applied]

Here's the element after applying flexbox (viewport width: 824px)

[image: .textWidget after flexbox applied]

Anyway, I hope this helps you. Cheers & Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I gave it an upvote. But I have gone with the advice provided in the comments which directly fixes the offending element styling within the widget.